# How can I use the scrollbar to scroll vertically through the buttons in the list?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, listbox, scrollbar

I need the buttons in the types list to scroll vertically using the scrollbar, but something is wrong with my code below. This is because the scrollbar works but the buttons in the list do not scroll using the scrollbar.
I tried putting numbers in the types list and that works very well, so why can't I put a list of buttons there and make them scroll?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('100x50')
window.minsize(10,5)

types = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

tscroll = tk.Scrollbar(window)

lb = tk.Listbox(window,bg = 'silver' )

tscroll.pack(side='left',fill='y')

lb.pack(side = 'left',fill = 'both')

def type1details():
    pass

count = 0
for t in types:
    button = ttk.Button(lb, text = t,command=type1details)
    lb.insert(count,button)
    button.pack()
    count += 1
lb.config(yscrollcommand = tscroll.set)
tscroll.config(command=lb.yview)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Listbox` widget is not designed to hold other widgets.  Use `Text` widget and `Text.window_create()` to insert widget into `Text` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listbox widget can only display strings so with this you can't display widgets like buttons, if you use canvas instead of listbox you can achieve your goal:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('100x150')
window.minsize(10, 5)

types = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg='silver', width=100, height=150, 
highlightthickness=0)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(window, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='silver')
frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: 
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor='nw')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

def type1details():
      pass

for t in types:
button = ttk.Button(frame, text=t, command=type1details)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the explanation and the code are just what I need!

Comment: I've tried this code and it works great!

Comment: I just found out I haven't accepted your answer yet. I'm a newcomer to StackOverflow, so I didn't notice there's an accept button there, my upvote didn't show up before either, so please don't mind the late acceptance, your answer did help me a lot!